# Is it possible to sync pinned tabs in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Question pretty much says it all. I'd like to have my pinned tabs automatically open up in Chrome across systems.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome syncs tabs, but doesn't (yet) sync tab pin status for some reason (even though that's available [via Chrome API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab)). So I'm afraid not (yet). Might consider posting a request on [Chrome's bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: @CrabbyAdmin you're welcome

Answer (score 3):

The status of this in Chrome's bug tracker is `WontFix` and the explanation looks quite reasonable: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=179846

Too bad, I also wanted to sync  pinned tabs :(

Comment: How is that explanation reasonable ? The idea behind pinned tabs is to have static URLs attached to them. You navigate somewhere the sync should IGNORE it. When we close & re-open pinned tabs should STAY at their pinned location. Take for example XYplorer, when you Lock a tab, and try navigating away, it just smartly opens a new tab for you.